# When checkbox is uncheck, I want to return all my list

Tags: arrays, angular, checkbox, boolean, boolean-expression

when I uncheck my text box, its not returning an selectedItemsList
.Hope you understand my problem.

```
 changeSelection() {
            this.checkedIDs = []
            this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter((value, index) => {
              if (value.isChecked == true) {
               
                return value.isChecked
              }
            
                else{
                this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
              
              }
             
            });
          
            this.router.navigate(['pipeline/cluster/policies'])
            this.sendclusteridApi()
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
             if (value.isChecked == false){
                this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
              }
                else{
                this.selectedItemsList = this.ProductData;
              
              }
```

You are definitely wrong here. Doing the same thing in `if` and `else` conditions.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your respond, Yeah accidentally I repeated. if value.ischecked == false then return value.ischecked, else return selectedItems. Thats what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Make changes to this code as you need, follow same structure:

HTML:

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="showData()" (checked)="(isChecked)" (change)="isChecked = !isChecked"></mat-checkbox>

<!-- below part only to visually see the change  -->
<div *ngFor="let elem of displayedItems">
    <p>{{ elem.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
displayedItems = [];
selectedItemsList = [
        {
            item1: 'hello',
            name: 'item1',
        },
        {
            item2: 'hello',
            name: 'item3',
        },
        {
            item3: 'hello',
            name: 'item3',
        },
    ];

showData() {
        if (this.isChecked === false) {
            this.displayedItems = this.selectedItemsList;
        } else {
            this.displayedItems = [];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, I fixed problem, i need to pass event.And i did that.its similar to your solution